# Extracting text from a rectangle using iText ( .Net ) does give me the entire line

Tags: pdf, itext, text-extraction

The following is the code (using iText for.Net Version 7.0.4.0) that i am using for extracting the text from a pdf. What i have observed during my testing is it works well by only extracting the content within a rectangle for most of the pdf's. But for few of them it gives the **entire line** from the pdf. I know

> that the text snippets that intersect with the rect (so part of the text may be outside rect, iText doesn't cut text snippets in pieces).

But I want to understand what parameter in the pdf will be used in iText to split text.

```
        var reader = new PdfReader( filePath );
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument( reader );

        var addressRect = new Rectangle( 33, 190, 70, 42 ); // 

        var addressRegionFilter = new TextRegionEventFilter( addressRect );
        var filterListener = new FilteredTextEventListener( new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), addressRegionFilter );
        var addressText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage( pdfDoc.GetPage( 1 ), filterListener );

        pdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: The functionality you are using evolved from version to version. The behavior you describe reminds me of the behavior of the early versions. That behavior changed in the later versions. Maybe your problem can't be reproduced in later versions. That would explain why no one is answering your question.

Comment: Are you referring to the version of iTextSharp ( iText ) or the version of pdf that i am trying extract text from. I can provide more details on those if necessary.

Comment: I'm referring to the version of iText. Note that we don't use the name iTextSharp anymore, because there's a company named Sharp that doesn't like other brands to use the word Sharp. We talk about iText for Java and about iText for .NET.

Comment: Thank you for clearing on the naming convention. I am using iText for .Net Version 7.0.4.0

Comment: That's very new. That should work, but maybe you're using the wrong filter. I'll leave this to someone else at iText who is more up-to-date with respect to the text extraction functionality.

Comment: The filter does work for some of the pdfs giving me only the content that intersect with the rectangle. For some other pdfs, it gives me the entire line even though there is lot of white space after the rectangle before the start of next word.

Comment: That's because of the way the PDF was created. The content of a page consists of a stream of operators and operands. Text is drawn using *show text* instructions that draw snippets of text at an absolute position. Sometimes, such a snippet consists of a full line, but most of the times a line consists of many small snippets. The text extractor will show you all the snippets that intersect with the rectangle you defined, but I'm pretty sure iText 7 is capable of clipping all the text that is drawn outside of the rectangle. It's just that I don't know the iText syntax to achieve this.

Comment: Appreciate your real time responses. I was also under the same impression that it is some attribute in the generated pdf that is causing the issue. I would love to know the syntax on how to circumvent the problem. I am all ears to know the syntax. ( I am doing a POC to extract text from one of our client generated pdf on which i have little control )

Comment: I'm in the Bay Area; the people who know the syntax are in Belgium. It's 5:40 PM where I am, but 2:40 AM where they are. You'll have to wait until it's morning over there...

Comment: Hi, I am still looking for some kind of help in this regard. If anyone can point to a filter to use, I can play around myself to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
class RectangleTextExtractionStrategy implements ITextExtractionStrategy
{

    private ITextExtractionStrategy innerStrategy = null;
    private Rectangle rectangle;

    public RectangleTextExtractionStrategy(ITextExtractionStrategy strategy, Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        this.innerStrategy = strategy;
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
    }

    @Override
    public String getResultantText() {
        return innerStrategy.getResultantText();
    }

    @Override
    public void eventOccurred(IEventData iEventData, EventType eventType) {
        if(eventType != EventType.RENDER_TEXT)
            return;
        TextRenderInfo tri = (TextRenderInfo) iEventData;
        for(TextRenderInfo subTri : tri.getCharacterRenderInfos())
        {
            Rectangle r2 = new CharacterRenderInfo(subTri).getBoundingBox();
            if(intersects(r2))
               innerStrategy.eventOccurred(subTri, EventType.RENDER_TEXT);
        }
    }

    private boolean intersects(Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        // # TODO
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<EventType> getSupportedEvents() {
        return innerStrategy.getSupportedEvents();
    }
}
```

The idea here is to split all incoming TextRenderInfo objects into the corresponding events for their characters. Then (if they are in the search region) we delegate the call to another ITextExtractionStrategy.

Comment: Thank you that works!!. I have added the code required for intersects. Let me know if any one needs c# version of the above code.

Comment: @Sridhar: Could you share with me the C# version. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Sridhar: Could you please share the code for intersect method?