# iText 7 - Extract Exact Word(s) In A Region

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

With PDF I understand that char/words can be positioned into multiple locations. I understand also this

> (so part of the text may be outside rect, iText doesn't cut text
> snippets in pieces)

I found this help also.
[Extracting text from a rectangle using iText ( .Net ) does give me the entire line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396905/extracting-text-from-a-rectangle-using-itext-net-does-give-me-the-entire-li?newreg=e04dec5e33284110ada550bee1eb98d3)

And managed the code below, but I still couldn't extract the exact word inside my rectangle.

```
namespace iText
{
    public static class Test
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            var reader = new PdfReader("mypdf.pdf");
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader);

            var addressRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);  

            var addressRegionFilter = new TextRegionEventFilter(addressRect);
            var filterListener = new RectangleTextExtractionStrategy(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), addressRect);
            var addressText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(1), filterListener);

            pdfDoc.Close();

        }
    }
    public class RectangleTextExtractionStrategy : ITextExtractionStrategy
    {
        private ITextExtractionStrategy innerStrategy = null;
        private Rectangle rectangle;

        public RectangleTextExtractionStrategy(ITextExtractionStrategy strategy, Rectangle rectangle)
        {
            this.innerStrategy = strategy;
            this.rectangle = rectangle;
        }

        public void EventOccurred(IEventData iEventData, EventType eventType)
        {
            if (eventType != EventType.RENDER_TEXT)
                return;
            TextRenderInfo tri = (TextRenderInfo)iEventData;
            foreach (TextRenderInfo subTri in tri.GetCharacterRenderInfos())
            {
                Rectangle r2 = new CharacterRenderInfo(subTri).GetBoundingBox();
                if (Intersects(r2))                  
                    innerStrategy.EventOccurred(subTri, EventType.RENDER_TEXT);
            }
        }

        public string GetResultantText()
        {
            return innerStrategy.GetResultantText();            
        }

        public ICollection<EventType> GetSupportedEvents()
        {
            return innerStrategy.GetSupportedEvents();
        }

        private bool Intersects(Rectangle rectangle)
        {
            var addressRect = new Rectangle(62, 20, 6, 7);
            bool intersect = rectangle.Contains(addressRect);

            if(intersect)
                return true; 

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"but I still couldn't extract the exact word inside my rectangle"_ - what happens? Do you get an error? If so what?  Does something fail _gracefully?_

Comment: There where no errors, but the output is not the same of what inside the rectangle.